# MySQL - on duplicate key - CASE WHEN THEN ELSE doesnt work

Tags: mysql, sql, on-duplicate-key, select-case

I want to insert an entry (uid, A, B) to database. If the entry is existed already, I will update the 'A' and 'B' column with condition:
([1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3660572/p-jairaj) = old entry; [2] = new entry)

```
A = (B[1] == B[2]) ? A[1] : A[2];
B = B[2] + 1;
```

My query:

```
INSERT INTO TableName (uid,A,B) 
VALUES (uid,A[2],B[2]) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE  A= (SELECT CASE B WHEN B[2] THEN A ELSE A[2] END), 
        B= B[2]+1;
```

Ex1:

```
Old entry : uid = 1; A = 2; B = 4;
New entry : uid = 1; A = 3; B = 4;
-> Should be: A = 2; B = 5;
But my result: A = 3; B = 5; -> FAIL
```

Ex2:

```
Old entry : uid = 1; A = 2; B = 4;
New entry : uid = 1; A = 3; B = 6;
-> A = 3; B = 7; (my code works well in this ex) -> OK
```

Thank you very much.

Answer 1: remove SELECT key make it work

```
INSERT INTO TableName (uid,A,B) 
VALUES (uid,A[2],B[2]) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE  A= (CASE B WHEN B[2] THEN A ELSE A[2] END), 
        B= B[2]+1;
```

Answer of [p-jairaj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3660572/p-jairaj)

```
INSERT INTO TableName (uid,A,B) 
VALUES (uid,A[2],B[2]) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE  A= (IF(B=B[2],A,A[2])), 
        B= B[2]+1;
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get a syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO TableName (uid,A,B) 
VALUES (uid,A[2],B[2]) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE  A= (IF(B=B[2],A,A[2])), 
        B= B[2]+1;
```